# Django make field disabled depending on another field value

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and trying to do something with an issue.I have this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, choises=...)
    custom_value = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

And I need custom_value field to be enabled to edit only if value of value field is "CUSTOM".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say 'enabled to edit' you are referring to a form field. 
I'm also assuming that the data will already be saved in the model when the form loads.

In that case, this should be done on the corresponding Form for that model. You'll need to initialize that form field to be disabled, and then enable it on the form load.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        custom_value = self.fields.get('custom_value')
        if custom_value and custom_value.widget.attrs['value'] == 'CUSTOM':
            self.fields['value'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'false'
```

I know your code is just an example, but using `value` as class attribute name is confusing.

If you were hoping to do this dynamically on one form, as in having a user select a choice and then see another option become enabled without a browser refresh, that must be done in Javascript. This is how you would do it with just Django forms.